# Style Material UI Data Grid for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Struggling to style the MUI Data Grid Component.

[image]

Specifically the white section. I cannot seem to change the colour of 'rows per page' or the pagination. Also seems that some of the icons are overlapping, you can see in the column header Proposal ID as well as the pagination arrows seem to overlapp.

Heres is the code:

```
import styles from "./votetab.module.scss";
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const VoteTab = ({}) => {
    const rows = [
        { id: 1, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'FOR', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 2, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 3, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 4, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 5, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 6, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 7, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 8, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 9, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 10, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
        { id: 11, ProposalID: 5912, Vote: 'Against', VotingPower: 100, tx: '0x124958910241'},
      ];
      const columns = [
        { field: 'ProposalID', headerName: 'Proposal ID', width: 150},
        { field: 'Vote', headerName: 'Vote', width: 150},
        { field: 'VotingPower', headerName: 'Voting Power', width: 150},
        { field: 'tx', headerName: 'Tx Hash', width: 415},
      ];

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Vote</h1>
    <div className={styles.grid}>
    <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            disableColumnSelector
    />
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default VoteTab;
```

styling:

```
.MuiDataGrid-cell{
  color: #F7F8DA;
  border-left: solid 1px #F7F8DA;
  
}
.MuiDataGrid-columnHeader{
  color: #83ddbc;
  font-family: 'Turret Road';
  background-color: red;
}


.MuiDataGrid-footerContainer{
  color: #83ddbc;
  font-family: 'Turret Road';
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

On the MUI website the default data grid is:
[image]

Comment: So you want the table to be like the first image ?

Comment: More like the second!

Comment: that's the default DataGrid in dark mode, so you have to find a way to force dark mode

Comment: Okay ill try that thanks! any idea why my icons are all messed up though, not sure if its obvious but my header icon as well as my pagination ones seemed to be stacked for some reason.

Comment: did you install the mui icons? I guess if you install it , it will work well

Comment: Thanks for the dark mode tip! it works now its white. However still cant get my icons to load correctly :( ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling but they still seem to overlap.